# write the data according to the name of the cell using java

Tags: java, excel, excel-formula, apache-poi, jxls

I have a problem. If I have an excel template, can I customize a name or logo for the cell, and then write the data according to the name of the cell using java

Comment: Check the below java module which is used to customize the cells entry using java https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFWorkbook.html

Comment: Manually create an excel template and mark the cell, and then the program writes data according to the mark

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.